# .htaccess rewriterule pattern Hash twitter

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, twitter, hashtag

I want to catch a link containing #.

Consider:

```
RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule pattern target [flags]
```

The question in here is the pattern portion. since `\#` isnt working. is there any other way to read/catch a hash in the incoming link?

Just like twitter does: http://twitter/#chakku will redirect you to tweets containing #chakku.

Answer (score 1):

The `#` and everything after it is the URL Fragment, it will **never** get sent to the server. Therefore, neither apache nor mod_rewrite will even know it exists.

Fragments are primarily used on the client/browser side, so you'll probably need something like javascript in order to trap it.

Comment: Hi @jon-lin I get that, but consider this:

To resolve http://www.domain.com/#topic I could have a rule like

<code>RewriteRule ^ index.html [L] </code>

and in Index.html I have a script loaded on window load. where i can redirect appropriately. Is this the optimum way of dealing with this?

Like for example http://www.twitter.com/#JonLin would redirect me to  that topic's page. Is that how theyve implemented that?

And if so, whats the use of .htaccess file.

Comment: @Hishaam htaccess has no play here at all. On the page *located at* `domain.com` (presumably, some index.html or something), you have javascript that looks at the URL and parse out the fragment. Nothing in the htaccess file will help you with fragments.

Comment: I have an AngulrJS based project. htaccess is a necessity for html5mode routeprovider. Thing is, in this config all links are redirected to index.html, and angular internally take cares of routing. So if i load a script on body's load every other route will have to call it. You think that side effect cant be dodged?